# Error showing "Description: The requested resource is not available."

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am deploying my Spring-Hibernate web application on "https://app.j.layershift.co.uk/" server. But it is showing error "The requested resource is not available".

This is very small web application on Spring-Hibernate. I made a zip file and upload it on server but server gives error at time of deployment.

**Dispatcher Servlet:**

```
<bean id="cradentials" class="com.webscreen.bean.Cradentials" />


    <bean id="cradentialsService" class="com.webscreen.service.CradentialsService"/>
    <bean id="cradentialsDao" class="com.webscreen.dao.CradentialsDao"/>



<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.webscreen.controller"></context:component-scan>

          <!-- we will manage transactions with annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


      <!-- we can use annotations -->
    <context:annotation-config />  
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


     <!-- data source for our database -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/screenshots" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>

         <!-- configure hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.webscreen.bean.Cradentials</value>


        </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>      
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Could you please share the server logs? Application is failing on start up.

Comment: And what request URLs are you sending?

Comment: is the name of your web app context file dispatcher-servlet.xml ?! or is it something else?